# when using FileDate----The Creation date of a file is not available on Macintosh and Unix?

Tags: files-and-directories

when I use

```
FileDate[filename,"Creation"]
```

it gives messages like

> FileDate::nocreationunix: The Creation date of a file is not available
>   on Macintosh and Unix. >>
>
> FileDate::nocreationunix: The Creation date of a file is not available
>   on Macintosh and Unix. >>
>
> FileDate::nocreationunix: The Creation date of a file is not available
>   on Macintosh and Unix. >>

Why?

**Edit**

I forgot to say my OS. My OS is Linux. As george2079 said, Linux don't have creation date. 
But I found `FileDate[filename,"Change"]` works like "Creation" in windows system.

Comment: useful information - OS version, Mathematica version,...

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, version 10.9, *Mathematica* version 9.0.1 can distinguish between creation and modification dates. For a typical notebook:

```
DateDifference[
      FileDate[filename, "Creation"], 
      FileDate[filename, "Modification"], 
   "Minute"]
```

returns

```
{126.083, "Minute"}
```

which I presume means that this file was worked on during a period of about two hours.

Answer (score 0):

Linux simply does not store creation date. (Its ultimately an ambiguous quantity).

Presumably macs are the same, being linux based. (Thought way back when  the original mac system did track creation date)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian

Comment: OS X does store file cration date.

Comment: I can confirm that Mathematica returns a file date creation on my Mac (OS X 10.8.5, MMA v9.0.1).

Comment: then how can I distinguish two files from the date. If one of the file is just a copy of the other, they have the same modified timestamp.

Comment: what difference does it make?

Comment: OS X is not Linux based; it is Free BSD based.

Comment: My bad, should have said *unix-ish*. In any case on further investigation it seems while POSIX compliant systems doent track creation *per se*, the information *may be* available on the raw file system, ie the results depend on the specific file system in use.

Comment: @george2079 thank you! I found that "Change" option works to distinguish files in Linux